# Tcl NameSpaces: How to Keep Global Variables separate from other Namespaces?

Tags: namespaces, tcl

Why doesn't this work?  (I expect 'puts $top' to print "vega"):

```
set top vega

namespace eval ::other {set top NULL}

puts $top ;
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer in detail can be found here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M26

Because you did not declare "top" to be a variable in that namespace, the `set` command continued to the global namespace to resolve the name `top`

You probably intended

```
set top vega
namespace eval ::other {
    variable top
    set top NULL
}
puts $top          ;# outputs "vega"
puts $other::top   ;# outputs "NULL"
```

But read that link at the top for all the wrinkles

Comment: What if I don't know what variables are going to be defined, for example, when sourcing a file?:
`
namespace eval ::other {
  source other.tcl
}
`

Comment: Then the global variables in "other.tcl" will be global in your script.

Comment: So I guess the best thing to do is use a proc, then.
Thanks!

Comment: The best thing is “use `variable` to declare when not in a procedure(-like context)”.